# HTML/CSS: Unwanted gap when box of text is embedded within other box of text

Tags: html, css

I am wondering **why the 4th line of text in green box is not starting from left like 5th line?** why there is that gap? How can I make the 4th line also start as left as 5th line?

[image]

The code for above page I have written is as below:

```css
div 
    {   text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-word;  }

    .t1 { font-size: 30px; margin:0px;  padding:10px; background:green;}
    .t2 { font-size: 10px; margin:20px; padding:10px; background:red; 
          width: 200px; float:left;}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >

    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div>
 <p class="t2">  This is red box. This is red box. This is red box. This is red box. This is red box. This is red box. This is red box.
     This is red box. This is red box. This is red box. This is red box. </p>

 <p class="t1"> This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This
       is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is 
       green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green 
       box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box.
       This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This  
       is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is 
       green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green 
       box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. 
       This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. This is green box. 
 </p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you

Comment: it's because till line 4 **.t2** has margin try to remove bottom margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well:

```
.t2 { font-size: 10px; margin:20px 20px 0px 20px; padding:10px 10px 0px 10px; background:red; 
      width: 200px; float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you set `margin` to `t2`

thats why content of `t1` starts from `5th` line

Answer (score 1):

add margin-bottom:0; to .t2 or adjust to your requirements